# Splitting string in specific format which was created from int vector

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, boost, split

I wrote a program which creates comma separated string out of vector of int like below:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> Vec;
Vec.push_back(50);
Vec.push_back(60);
Vec.push_back(10);
Vec.push_back(20);
Vec.push_back(30);
Vec.push_back(2);
Vec.push_back(1);

std::stringstream lineNumString;
lineNumString.str(std::string());
lineNumString.clear();

std::copy(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(lineNumString, ","));

std::string lineString(lineNumString.str());
lineString = lineString.substr(0, lineString.length()-1);

std::cout << std::endl << lineString;
```

If you see output of above program is:

```
         `50,60,10,20,30,2,1`
```

But I want to change my output in some different format. I want to have maximum THREE numbers on one line and next numbers to next line. Like below:

```
50,60,10,
20,30,2,
1
```

I tried creating child vectors from `Vec` and tried using them to create different strings. Then I tried splitting `lineString` and then used those strings.
Please let me know if there is any better way to achieve final output? 
I am using VS2010. I can use BOOST features also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The classic loop way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::vector<unsigned int> Vec;
  Vec.push_back(50);
  Vec.push_back(60);
  Vec.push_back(10);
  Vec.push_back(20);
  Vec.push_back(30);
  Vec.push_back(2);
  Vec.push_back(1);


  for(auto it = Vec.begin(); it != Vec.end();)
  {
    std::cout << *it++;

    if(it != Vec.end())
      std::cout << ",";

    if((it - Vec.begin()) % 3 == 0)
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

The Boost.spirit way:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
  std::vector<unsigned int> v = {50, 60, 10, 20, 30, 2, 1};

  using karma::int_;
  using karma::eol;
  using karma::duplicate;
  using karma::generate;

  std::string out;
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> it(out);

  generate(it, int_ << "," << *(int_ << "," << int_ << "," << duplicate[ &int_ << eol << int_ << ","]), v);

  out[out.size() - 1] = 0;
  std::cout << out << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The little trick with `duplicate`: it duplicates attribute `int_`, which is mandatory, because predicate `&` consume it, in order to know if we display the end of the line (`eol`) or not.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way we can do this without looping the vector?

Comment: Boost spirit could be used here ... See the edit of my post !